# Android - MySQL Login (Auto Fill)

Tags: android, mysql, authentication

I have an android application that requres a login based on users in a SQL database.

We are wanting to steer away from user names as the primary login will be for a school full of students. Can you auto fill (while typing) in a text widget with student names from the SQL database? If so, would it be quick enough?

Basically I want to start typing a student's name and it auto fill like when you are typing a text Message to a friend in your contact list. Thus no usernames will have to be generated.

A simple yes or no would suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can, using an [AutoCompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html).  But if it's a remote database you'll probably want to query it and have the data around before they try to start typing.